# What is a Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) server?

Tags: networking, dns, network-protocols, dhcp

What is a Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol(DHCP) server? and What is the difference between DHCP server and 
a Domain Name Server(DNS) server?

Answer (score 2):

**DHCP** *(Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol)*

is for assigning IP addresses (or other network parameters) to devices so they can communicate with each other.

If you for example want to establish a wireless connection, then you need amongst other things request a DHCP server that assigns your device an IP address so you can communicate with other nodes.

---

**DNS** *(Domain Name System)*

is a hierarchical decentralised service which associates informations with domain names.

If you for example want to request *google.com* you first need to figure out what the corresponding IP address is. Therefore you request a DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP is a layer 2 network protocol that will offer IP address from its pool to device not connected to the network, but who wanted to. It's used in LAN network.

DNS is like a dictionary. Consider you are trying to go to stackoverflow.com, so your device isn't able to know what's the IP address of stackoverflow.com. He will ask to DNS server to found the IP address for him.

**DHCP = IP dynamic allocation**

**DNS = IP retrieval of an existing and registered device**