# What is actual full form of DHCP? what does C stands for control or configuration

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

What is the actual full form of DHCP
Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol
or
Dynamic Host Control Protocol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097188/what-is-a-dynamic-host-configuration-protocol-dhcp-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol

check out more info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol)